# Y to Delta transform with inductors?

Tags: inductor, y-to-delta

Does a Y to delta transform for resistors work the same way when inductors a connected in a similar fashion?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9l9Xf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a load bank that is wired in a Y configuration. I'm given the specks for loading in a delta configuration. I'm trying to figure out if these loads will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Y to Δ conversion formula remains the same for all impedances (\$Z\$). In case the impedance is just a resistor, replace \$Z\$ with \$R\$. In the case of an inductor, replace with \$Z=j L \omega\$. In the case of a capacitor, it must be \$Z=1/(j C \omega)\$. In case of combinations of these elements, add them and replace \$Z\$.

Answer (score 1):

> Does a Y to delta transform for resistors work the same way when inductors a connected in a similar fashion?

yes. Absolutely identical. Same applies to capacitors, or any general complex impedance element.